# Drop parameters in generator macro

Tags: c, gcc, enums, c-preprocessor

I'm currently working on a code base with an extreme amount of enums. There is a need to convert `enum` values to and from string representations. To do this there is a bunch of helper macros that operates on macros on the form

```c
#define THINGS_MAP(G, P) \
    G(LAMP, P) \
    G(DESK, P)
```

And elsewhere in the code there are macros that works roughly like this:

```c
#define MK_ENUM(SYM, P) P##_##SYM,
enum { THINGS_MAP(MK_ENUM, THING) }; /* expands to { THING_LAMP, THING_DESK, } */
```

I would like to avoid changing `MK_ENUM` and the call to `THINGS_MAP` inside the enum.

However, I now have one particularly long `enum` list, where I also need to add some classification to the entries. So I was thinking about doing something like

```c
#define THINGS_PROP_MAP(G, P) \
    G(LAMP, WOODEN, P) \
    G(DESK, METALIC, P)
```

However, since all my helper macros require two arguments passed, not three, I was thinking if it would be possible to map some kind of macro that drops a parameter. Is this possible?

What I am looking for is something along the lines of:

```c
#define THINGS_PROP_MAP(G, P) \
    G(LAMP, WOODEN, P) \
    G(DESK, METALIC, P)

/* DROP_PROP should create G(LAMP, P) G(DESK, P) */
#define THINGS_MAP(G, P) DROP_PROP(THINGS_PROP_MAP)
```

One idea I had was to add an extra transformation step, but I didn't get it to work

```c
#define THINGS_PROP_MAP(G, T, P) \
    G(T(LAMP, WOODEN, P)) \
    G(T(DESK, METALIC, P))
#define DROP_PROP(SYM, _ , P) SYM, P
#define THING_MAP(G, P) THING_PROP_MAP(G, DROP_PROP, P)
```

And yes, I know this is waaay beyond macro abuse etc :-)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't generate the code using external scripts, say awk? For example, having the header file that defines the enums include an automatically generated header file. It's all quite straightforward to automate in a Makefile. If you do have a lot of enums or need a lot of macro magic, generating the definitions externally, instead of using complicated macro magic, *should* be easier to maintain.

Comment: Hmm, in retrospective that could have been a better idea :-). Much of it started the way it usually does with the code becoming more and more complex as the time goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your macros are fine but your `#define MK_ENUM(SYM, P) P##_##SYM,` expects two parameters where this call `G(T(LAMP, WOODEN, P))` for example with `G = MK_ENUM` invokes `G` with just one parameter even though the inner statement would expand to `LAMP, P`.

To force the preprocessor to do one additional expansion step and recognize that `LAMP, P` is not a single token you must add:

```
#define MK_ENUM_EXPAND(...) MK_ENUM(__VA_ARGS__)
```

and then use:

```
enum { THING_MAP(MK_ENUM_EXPAND, THING) };
```

Further notice that your macro doesn't expand to `enum { THING_LAMP, THING_DESK };` but with a comma at the end to `enum { THING_LAMP, THING_DESK, };`.

**Full working code:**

```
#define MK_ENUM(SYM, P) P##_##SYM,
#define MK_ENUM_EXPAND(...) MK_ENUM(__VA_ARGS__)

#define THINGS_PROP_MAP(G, T, P) \
    G(T(LAMP, WOODEN, P)) \
    G(T(DESK, METALIC, P))

#define DROP_PROP(SYM, _ , P) SYM, P

#define THINGS_MAP(G, P) THINGS_PROP_MAP(G, DROP_PROP, P)

enum { THINGS_MAP(MK_ENUM_EXPAND, THING) }; /* expands to { THING_LAMP, THING_DESK, } */
```

To test macro expansion it is useful to use gcc with the command line argument `-E`:

```
$ gcc -E srcFile.c
```

because your're getting concrete error messages and understand what's going wrong.

---

If you don't want to change `MK_ENUM` and the call to `THINGS_MAP` inside the enum you can do the following where I just concatenate `G##S` in `THINGS_PROP_MAP` where `G = MK_ENUM` and `S = _EXPAND`:

```
#define MK_ENUM(SYM, P) P##_##SYM,
#define MK_ENUM_EXPAND(...) MK_ENUM(__VA_ARGS__)

#define THINGS_PROP_MAP(G, S, T, P) \
    G##S(T(LAMP, WOODEN, P)) \
    G##S(T(DESK, METALIC, P))

#define DROP_PROP(SYM, _ , P) SYM, P

#define THINGS_MAP(G, P) THINGS_PROP_MAP(G, _EXPAND, DROP_PROP, P)

enum { THINGS_MAP(MK_ENUM, THING) }; /* expands to { THING_LAMP, THING_DESK, } */
```

Comment: That was perhaps a bit unclear in my question, but problem is that the `enum` macros are already defined and requires something on the form `THING_MAP(G, P)`, and I would like to have to change the rest of the code due to a special case for one structure. But perhaps this solution works for that case as well...

Comment: You're saying: `I would like to avoid changing these macros, if possible.` But after that you're showing your attempts where you change `THINGS_MAP`. I'm unsure what exactly you want, so please try to explain it and edit your question so that others or me can give an accurate answer.

Comment: If possible I would like to only change `THINGS_MAP` to make it usable by `MK_ENUM`. Will clarify

Comment: I added a version that avoids changing those you don't want to change.